# iOS: Switching between views quickly causes data being passed to be incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, view

In my iOS app, I have made it so that when I segue from the main view to a second view data is passed, and then when I go back to the main view, data is passed back to it (using a protocol). This works fine if I segue between views slowly, but once I start doing it quickly, (spamming "push" and "back" buttons) the data becomes wrong. I use the prepareForSegue,viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods to transfer data.

If anyone else has had a similar problem and can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? To pass data you should only need prepareForSegue going forward. Going backward, viewWillDisappear in your second view should be enough to send data back. What do you use viewWillAppear for? Also make sure you are not setting UI content in prepareForSegue as the views may not be available. You have to set the UI content in viewWillAppear from data you setup in prepareForSegue. If your back data comes from a UI element on the second view, popping back may have prevented it from being filled in: assuming the navigation bar could get updated ahead of the views.

Comment: You need to provide more information. You're passing data forward in prepareForSegue, and backwards using a protocol, so what are you doing in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear?